# Где поставить "как"?

Tags: лексика, как

"График отпусков может оформляться (как) с использованием (как) бланка, так и чистых листов бумаги".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

График отпусков может оформляться  с использованием **как бланка**, **так и** чистых **листов** бумаги. Составной союз как ..так и используется  для соединения однородных членов. Перед ними и ставится.